# Виндовый хостинг и винда

Tags: хостинг, vps, домен, windows-server, vds

Я никогда не использовал виндовый хостинг, прошу просветить на счёт особенностей по сравнению с линуксовым. Собственно, меня интересует возможность зайти из под винды как на сервере, то-есть - VDS рулит, но там, почему-то, предлагается только один главный домен, и предлагается для разных сайтов довольствоваться поддоменами - из-за этого я не беру сервер. Как быть? Получится-ли на VDS сделать сайты с разными доменами?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. VDS имеет один или несколько IP-адресов, на которые можно подключать бесконечно много абсолютно любых доменов, и никто не может вам запретить их подключать (лишь бы у вас деньги на них были). Наличие или отсутствие винды здесь абсолютно ни при чём

Comment: Вообще, сервер и домен - вещи никак не связанные, вы можете подключать свои домены даже к чужим серверам (только чужие серверы скорее всего откажутся обрабатывать запросы с "неожиданными" доменами)

Comment: Мне это не понятно: почему тогда хостер отказывается подключать мне больше одного домена? Пишет - что после первого можно подключать только поддомены?..

Comment: Или может он предлагает это в рамках услуги - а потом, отдельно от него, я могу ещё чегонить понаподключать? Тогда не понятно - а как у него возиться с IP? Это для каждого нового домена нежен свой IP, ели я вас правильно понял.

Comment: Я не знаю, что за дичь творит ваш хостинг. Вообще, лучше покупать домены отдельно от хостинга, напрямую у регистраторов, чтобы хостинг можно было спокойно менять - не надо класть все яйца в одну корзину. Нет, на одном IP может быть бесконечно много доменов

Comment: Дело в том - что разговор с хостером сводится к: ...купите - мы вам поставим виндоус и делайте - что хотите... А я не могу по этим сведениям принять решение - мне надо представлять - как это делается. Точнее: как на VPS-е под виндой поставить платформу для сайтов, как назначать им уникальные имена и всё-такое. - Прошу направить на поучающее пособие.

Comment: Просто берите любой понравившийся учебник по Windows Server и выбранной вами реализации веб-сервера, VPS тут уже ни при чём

Comment: Будьте добры: 
Предлагается Windows Server Datacenter 2019 и просто Windows Server 2019 - что выбрать? - читаю - не нахожу (по неопытности) - на что мне добавка Datacenter?..

Comment: Надо понимать - это расширенная вертуализация? - никогда с этим не работал. У меня тариф с одним процессором и памятью в один гигабайт - ?

Comment: На одном гигабайте винда будет без рабочего стола. Вы точно уверены, что оно вам надо?

Comment: Затрудняюсь ответить. Я раньше использовал VPS с виндой - работало.
Где я ещё найду сервер за 250 р., с накопителем от двадцати гиг, и сверх-гигом оперативки?? Можете посоветовать?

На счёт Datacenter, вопрос, я так понимаю - вы важным не считаете?

Comment: Минимум накопителя для винды — 32 гиг, я не очень понимаю, как винда в принципе собирается запускаться на таких ничтожных характеристиках. Кроме того, вы не забыли учесть стоимость лицензии?

Comment: Лицензию я буду использовать кракнутую.
Мне сдаётся - вы преувеличиваете. А как, по вашему, вообще хостеры предлагают пакеты с виндой с такими скромными характеристиками? И, таки, это не единишное евление... И, таки, у меня есть неоднократный опыт этого использования, и, который показывает, что винда без наворотов в виде оффисов, игр, антивирусов и архиваторов, занимает очень мало места по сравнению с ПК-вариантом.

Comment: И хостинг даже позволяет вам использовать крак? Что блин за лютая дичь там у вас творится вообще